# FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

My script is failing when attempting to load the template, with the following error:

```
FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory exited with code 5
```

The code that I'm calling looks like this:

```
emailTemplates(templatesDir, function(err, template) {
    winston.info("Setting up templates.", templatesDir);
    if(err) {
        winston.error(err);
    }else{
        var today = new Date().getDay();
        winston.info("Found that today is ", aDays[today]);

        template("notify", {
            reports: [{
                item: "merged",
                desc: "Blah blah"
            },{
                item: "searched",
                desc: "Blah blah"
            }],
            vars: Operators.BBT.mail,
            day: aDays[today],
            fusionAPIRan: canRunFAPI
        }, function(err, html, text) {
            if(err) {
                winston.error(err);
            }else{
                winston.info("Attempting to send an email!");
                smtpTransport.sendMail({
                    from: "Webmaster <webmaster@example.co.uk>",
                    to: "james@example.co.uk",
                    subject: "Worker - Notification Email",
                    html: html
                }, function(error, response){
                    if(error){
                        winston.error(error);
                        cb(false);
                    }else{ 
                        winston.info("Message sent: " + response.message + ", message id: " + response.messageId);
                        cb(true);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

It gets as far as `Found that today is xxx` and the `winston.error` inside doesn't get called. What's causing that? A dodgy template perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of digging and debugging, I've managed to find the cause of this issue. I am using  the [node-email-templates](https://github.com/niftylettuce/node-email-templates) which uses [EJS](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs) to process JavaScript code within a HTML template and then email it using [Nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer).

The problem occurs within the EJS module, specifically when trying to process variables **within** comments.

```
<!-- The entire job took <%= time => to complete. -->
```

The code within the comment `<%= time %>` causes a crash somewhere along the line. I've [reported this bug](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs/issues/110)  on the GitHub issues page of EJS. I'm going to attempt to fix it when I get some time at work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error, but my issue was that html2text was breaking one of my variables onto two lines, like

```
<%= var
%>
```

After correcting this so that the variable was all on one line, I no longer got the allocation error.